# Running python-socketio with SystemD to play sounds at background

Tags: python, socket.io, subprocess, systemd

My **SystemD service** file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=XXX
After=sound.target network.target
Wants=sound.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -u raspberry.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/Desktop
Restart=always
User=pi
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
Alias=XXX
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The python script is a classic **python-socketio client** which should listen for events like "listen" and "play". The main part of code looks like this:

```
import subprocess
import socketio

HOST = "https://XXX.ngrok.io"
sio = socketio.Client(engineio_logger=True)

...

@sio.on('play')
def play(data):
    print("play")
    subprocess.call(["espeak", "'Not working'"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    subprocess.call(["espeak","'Initialized'"]) 
    sio.connect(HOST)
    sio.wait()
```

When I set up the service to run at booting, the first calling of espeak is executed and socket connection with my server is established but then if I send an event (through my server) the second calling of espeak is not working (there is no sound). If I look into logs through `journalctl -u XXX` I will see that the function is called because the print statement is executed.

What comes to my mind is that it is because of running the subprocess call from a different thread, but I am not sure.. any ideas?

Comment: There can be problem with different thread because with them it is working 

`def threaded_function():
    subprocess.call(["espeak", "'Call from threaded function.'"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    subprocess.call(["espeak","'Initialized'"]) 
    thread = Thread(target = threaded_function)
    thread.start()
    thread.join()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is related to my other question at [Raspberry Pi forum](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98193/no-sound-as-root-and-even-with-sudo-su-pi/). The main problem was the inability of root to play sounds. When I was debugging this problem, I found that because of `User=pi` the service is started as **user pi**. But when I call `subprocess.call` in `@sio.on('play')` part it was under called as **user root**. It was happening only in `@sio.on('play')` part. If I did it in `if __name__ == '__main__':` part, the calling was under `pi` user. Still don't know why it was happening but solution was not using **AIY hat version of Raspbian** but classic version **Raspbian Stretch Lite**.